# How to share a fix between previous releases and current work in the cycle workflow?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I am wondering which route should I take, a cherry-pick or something else?

I have this branching tree:

```
          ReleaseX
       ^
      /
Master --> ReleaseY
   |
   V
WorkInProgress
   |        |        
   V        V
FeatureX  FeatureY    .. etc
```

So `WorkInProgress` branches off of `Master`, and when `WorkInProgress` is "done", I do "Pull Request" from it to `Master`, and then I branch off of `Master` to a new Branch and call it `ReleaseX`

This allows me to support releases and do hot-fixes on any Release branch separately.

I have two cases for my question here:

- Do a hotfix on `ReleaseX` and then apply it on `ReleaseY`
- Do a hotfix for `ReleaseX`, `ReleaseY` and also `WorkInProgress`

Is Cherry-Pick the way to go?

Comment: If you really need this hotfix in all three branches (which is _all_ your branches), then the cleanest thing to do might be to fix it in `master`, and then rebase each feature branch on `master`, or maybe do a merge with `master`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking that if I do it in `WorkInProgress` (Cherry-Pick from `ReleaseX`?), the fix would end in `Master` at some point(once work is done and I PullRequest from `WorkInProgress` into `Master`).

Comment: Yes, you can cherry-pick, but I don't like it in general, because then you have a handful of commits out there which functionally are almost identical, but yet are really different commits, with different SHA-1 hashes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Exactly why I am worried. I will wait for a good-put answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This sort of branching structure is something I would only recommend when you have to maintain ReleaseX and ReleaseY at the same time (if you do, good luck)*

In this situation I would advice fixing the bug on the Release branch where it is found first (in a separate hotfix branch which you merge back in). Then cherry-picking those commits to the other Release branches.

Generally I like to avoid cherry-picking as it creates hard to follow duplicate commits, but the action is better than modifying history (rebasing) commits that have been shared and marked as release.

Comment: Yes, the my main purpose of this structure is to support multiple previous release at the same time. So, cherry pick is that way to go? And why to do the hotfix on a separate branch and not on the Release branch directly?

Comment: In general I like to keep all work done on separate feature/bugfix/hotfix branches as it makes it clear that it was a single unit of work without limiting myself to single commits.
In addition it allows you to limit work going to dev/master by using pull requests and code reviews, preventing catastrophic danger from occurring, hopefully.